# Consecutive inlines produces space inbetween

Tags: xsl-fo

I have a simple XSL FO with a block containing consecutive inlines.

```
<fo:block-container span="all">
    <fo:block font-family="Calibri" font-size="12"
      color="#108BA4" line-height="1.15" widows="3" orphans="3"
      keep-with-next="always" span="all">
      <fo:inline font-family="Calibri"
        font-weight="normal" font-size="11" color="#108BA4">Sous-article de 2
      </fo:inline>
      <fo:inline vertical-align="super">nd</fo:inline>
      <fo:inline font-family="Calibri"
        font-weight="normal" font-size="11" color="#108BA4"> génération
      </fo:inline>
    </fo:block>
  </fo:block-container>
```

Thing is I get some sort of whitespace between "2" and "nd" and probably between "nd" and "génération".
Also because someone is going to ask, I have this in my XSL :

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

Any idea ?

[Image of what I get in the PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y29mM.jpg)

Comment: Because you do have whitespace between them. Showing what you have in your XSL file and what is output in your XSL FO is of no value. Certainly xsl:strip-space has absolutely nothing to do with what you show us in XSL FO except what you thought it was doiing, it didn't. Perhaps you want to try normalize-space() on the elements you are outputting to your FO but since you do not share your XSL we can only guess.

Comment: Also, just a note in the output. span="all" on the child fo:block is worthless and actually an error. The span="all" on the block-container you start with might be OK if the parent is fo:flow.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing the effect of the white-space after the "2" in:

```
      <fo:inline font-family="Calibri"
        font-weight="normal" font-size="11" color="#108BA4">Sous-article de 2
      </fo:inline>
```

`<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` only applies to your source document. (See the XSLT 1.0 definition at https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#strip.) It won't do anything to your stylesheet.

White-space-only text nodes in your stylesheet are stripped automatically (unless they are within an `xsl:text` element).  Your text node has non-white-space characters, so nothing is being stripped.  If you looked at the result of the XSLT transformation, you'd see the line end and the white-space before the `</fo:inline>`.  The formatter is reducing that to just a single space for you.